# how to trigger click event of input file from button click in angular 2?

Tags: file, file-upload, angular

```html
<input type="file" accept="image/*">

<button>Upload file</button>
```

How to trigger click event of input type=file from button's click event in Angular 2?

Answer (score 154, accepted):

You can leverage template reference variable as follows:

```html
<input type="file" accept="image/*" #file>
<button (click)="file.click()">Upload file</button>
```

The corresponding plunkr is here https://plnkr.co/edit/JB4HY0oxEUgXXIht2wAv?p=preview

Comment: is it safe to use. Will clicking the file input programatically work across different browsers on desktop and mobile in 2018.

Answer (score 19):

You could do have declare variable for input file field as `#file` & then only file change do call `upload` function to pass uploaded file to function.

```
<input #file type="file" accept="image/*" (change)="upload(file.files)">

<button #upload (click)="file.click()">Upload file</button>
```

Comment: To hide native file input, you can add `[style.visibility]="'hidden'"`   or display & none

Answer (score 12):

In Angular 4,

HTML:

```
<input #fileUpload type="file" (click)="fileUpload.value = null"(change)="importFile($event)" style="display:none"
accept="image/*">
<button (click)="fileUpload.click()">  </button>
```

Typescript:

```
importFile(event) {

if (event.target.files.length == 0) {
   console.log("No file selected!");
   return
}
  let file: File = event.target.files[0];
  // after here 'file' can be accessed and used for further process
}
```

On considering the future issue of selecting same file not working, In input tag click event we are setting to null, which allows same file to select second time.

Answer (score 11):

In Angular 4,

HTML:

```
<ion-input type="file" formControlName="avatar"></ion-input>
<button type="button" ion-button (click)="selectFile()"></button>
```

Javascript:

```
selectFile() {
    let element: HTMLElement = document.querySelector('input[type="file"]') as HTMLElement;
    element.click();
}
```

It's work for me.

Comment: That's ionic as far as I see

Comment: Seem to me that this one is good solution instead of using Angular template reference variable.  However, How can I call let element: HTMLElement = document.querySelector('input[type="file"]') as HTMLElement if input is in different typescript files.

Answer (score 3):

You can write something like this if you want to gracefully display the name of the uploaded file.

```
<div style="display:flex; flex-direction: row;">
  <input type="text" disabled value="{{fileName}}">
  <button (click)="fileInput.click()">File Upload </button>
  <input #fileInput type="file" (change)="onChange($event)" style="display:none"/>
</div>
```

In your TS file you'll have to make following changes

```
  fileName: string = "";
  onChange(event) {
    this.fileName = event.target.files[0].name;
  }
```