# how to trigger event click at input type="file" by function in angular 2?

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, angular

I have this code in Html file .

```
<input #fileInput type="file"  />
```

**demo.ts**

```
import {
  Component,
  Inject,
  OnInit,
  ElementRef,
  Renderer,
  ViewQuery
} from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'demo',
  templateUrl: 'client/dev/demo/demo.html',
})
export class DemoComponent implements OnInit{

@ViewQuery('fileInput') fileInput:ElementRef;

constructor(){}

triggerFile(){
   // do something 
   // trigger input type="file" here
   this.fileInput.nativeElement.click();
}

ngOnInit() {


}

}
```

I see this answer : [how to trigger click event of input file from button click in angular 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37320135/how-to-trigger-click-event-of-input-file-from-button-click-in-angular-2)
Of course it worked . But I want to trigger input type="file" in triggerFile() function and I use ViewQuery and nativeElement.click() function . but it console this error "Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined" . I use angular2 Rc 1 . thank for help .

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Pass the `fileInput` reference to `triggerFile()` and do the `fileInput.click()` there instead:

```
<input #fileInput type="file"  />
<button type="button" (click)="triggerFile(fileInput)">trigger</button>
```

```
triggerFile(fileInput:Element) {
  // do something
  fileInput.click();
}
```

Comment: Can I ask you one more question ? how can I trigger event click by function in my ts file ( not by click on button )?

Comment: You can add `@ViewQuery('fileInput) fileInput:ElementRef;` to your component class, then you don't need to pass it from the view. Invoke the click using `this.fileInput.nativeElement.click();`

Comment: I use angular 2 Rc 1 . It console this error :"Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined" . It cann't use nativeElement ?

Comment: Did you remove `#fileInput` from the `<input type="file">`?

Comment: No , I didn't . It's still  <input #fileInput type="file" /> . I imported ViewQuery from @angular/core , Is It Problem ?

Comment: I was missing the closing `'` after `'fileInput`. I guess you added it. Please edit your question and post your current code.

Comment: I have edited my question and posted my code . thank you .

Comment: It doesn't contain the `@ViewQuery(...`

Comment: I edited my question clearer . I still used your code .

Comment: You don't by any chance call `triggerFile()` from within the `constructor()`? `@ViewChild()` is only set after `ngAfterContentInit()`.

Comment: Sorry, it's after `ngAfterViewInit()` for `@ViewChild`. I missed that you had it in `ngOnInit()`, that is still too early.

Comment: yes, my constructor don't has anything , I edited my code at ngOnInit , but it's still console that error  . did i use @ViewChild() correctly ?

Comment: See my previous comment `ngAfterViewInit()`

Comment: sorry , I don't understand your solution :( .

Comment: Call `triggerFile()` in `ngAfterViewInit()` not in `ngOnInit()`

Answer (score 6):

No need to write code in controller

```html
<input #fileInput type="file"  />
<button type="button" (click)="fileInput.click()">trigger</button>
```