# How can i trigger a click event (on a file type input) inside a promise?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise, dom-events

I've been having problems with this for a while and i can't find a solution anywhere, basically i am trying to trigger a click event on an input file type but this event needs to be triggered inside a promise, when i try to trigger the event directly inside the promise the console logs an error saying "digest in progress"
if i put a timeout inside the promise, the error disappears but the event is not triggered, the only way i have made this work is by adding a timeout for about a second outside the promise, but i really don't want to rely this event on a defined timeout

The controller looks something like this

```
scope.handleDblClick = function () {
    asyncFunction()
        .then(function (response){
            switch(response){
                case 'option1':
                    //do something
                    break;
                case 'option2':
                    document.getElementById('fileInputId').click();
                    break;
            }

        });
}
```

This function is triggered when this text input gets double clicked

```
<input type="text" ng-dblclick="handleDblClick()"/>
```

This is a file input that needs to be triggered inside the promise

```
<input type="file" id="fileInputId"/>
```

The event needs to be triggered this way because the result of the async function determines if the input file is going to be clicked or some other action will be taken, the handleDblClick function handles different actions based on the response of the promise, and one of those actions includes opening a file explorer to pick a file

Comment: What does your controller look like? And your component with the file input?

Comment: add the relevant code  also.

Comment: I've added the relevant part where my main problem is, and some more explanation

Comment: Do you have any click listenered added to the element? Or a normal `ng-click`? Triggering a click shouldn't cause an error if the element only have a dblclick listener attached. And if it has both, wrapping the click in setTimeout should work, tested it to confirm.

Comment: I've tried this, and yes this fixed the $digest error but for some reason the file explorer window is not poping up.

Comment: the element with the handleDblClick function attached is the one that gets triggered manually, by user interaction, but i need to trigger another click event(programatically) on another input as a consequence of that first dblclick

Comment: Didn't notice you were using an id for another input.

Comment: But you have managed to get the other input to open by triggering click programatically from elsewhere?

Comment: I changed the code trying to make it clearer, yes, i've managed to get this input triggered by adding the timeout outside the promise but only if i set a 1 second timeout, or just enough time for the promise to finish, also by console commands

Comment: Browser? Can you reproduce it here: http://plnkr.co/edit/Qhzc3EYBwJqGEtds953j?p=preview

Comment: Im using Chrome and this plunker gives me the same result, which is that no file explorer window pops up

Comment: Yes, that is expected so far. But even with triggering the click outside the promise I can't get it to open (you said that worked for you). Can you reproduce the working scenario? http://plnkr.co/edit/gXb6H5OgcHLqOSTfvIaF?p=preview

Comment: There, sorry for the delay on my answer but i changed the plnkr to the only way i have found to trgger the input, but i dont really wanna rely on this method

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to trigger event click at input type="file" by function in angular 2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38261859/how-to-trigger-event-click-at-input-type-file-by-function-in-angular-2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my own answer, turns out that java-script will only trigger the dialog box of an input file element if it comes from an event handler that was triggered by the user and it has to be trusted :) Thanks !

I'll leave the link here

https://github.com/angular/material/issues/8639