# fileInput.click() undefined

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am trying to give a file input in my angular material code:

HTML:

```
<mat-form-field class = "form-element">
<input matInput readonly placeholder = "fileInput" [formControl] = "filename" (click) = "fileInput.click()">
<span mat-button matSuffix mat-icon-button (click) = "fileInput.click()">
<mat-icon>attach_file</mat-icon>
<span>
</mat-form-field>
```

TS:

```
filename = new FormControl()
```

But when clicked on the button I am getting a console error saying 'cannot read property 'click' of undefined..??

Thanks in advance for the help..!!

Comment: couldn't understand fileInput.click(),is there any method in TS to be invoked while clicking the template.

Comment: no there is no such method in TS...i coded it according to the code I saw in other websites.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing in your code which defines what `fileInput` is. So `fileInput.click()` throws the error because`fileInput` is undefined.

If you want to access the input control, then you can do so by creating a [template reference variable](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#template-reference-variables-var).

Here is what your input would look like:

```
<input matInput readonly placeholder="fileInput" [formControl]="filename" #fileInput />
```

Comment: i followed [](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38261859/how-to-trigger-event-click-at-input-type-file-by-function-in-angular-2) this thread, this isnt working for me...

Comment: I tried that too, but then there is not even a console error, the field does nothing when clicked in this scenario

Comment: It's because you have also added a click handler to the input field which just calls it the click function on itself. So you put it in a recursive loop. You need to remove the click handler on your input and keep it on the span.