# open upload dialog by programility in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

i want to oen upload dialog by typescript in angular 9 .

i not want to using this way : create input and `dispaly:none`

```
<input type="file" ng2FileSelect [uploader]="uploader" style="display: none" />
```

i want to open file upload dialog with code .

**how open the upload file dialog without the create input file and just using the typescript or javascript Code ?**

Comment: I think there is no way to accomplish that, without actually having some kind of implementation that takes care of the file upload. So either you need to completely re-implement the entire API that usually takes care of the file upload, or have a hidden input that you may trigger as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37320135/how-to-trigger-click-event-of-input-file-from-button-click-in-angular-2

Comment: What have you tried so far in typescript/javascript? This is a very open question and you haven't provided anything to help us help you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If there is no file input then you can't open file browser. This file input is readonly input just one way and work while clicked due to security issues. Then You need file input to open dialog.

One  way is to use Viewchild and trigger click it.

in html write Viewchild name

```
<input type="file"  style="display: none;" #file />
```

in component can call it in ngAfterViewInit

```
 @ViewChild("file") file : ElementRef;

  ngAfterViewInit(){
    console.log(this.file.nativeElement);
    this.file.nativeElement.click(); 
  }
```